# why doesn't eclipse Helios web project find dependent project classes at runtime?

Tags: java, classpath, eclipse-wtp

My problem is almost exactly the same as [the one described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326689/eclipse-debug-time-classpath-problem-how-do-you-include-a-dependent-projects-o), but that post is a couple years old and eclipse helios (which I am using) doesn't appear to use the J2EE project labels that were discussed in that question.

I have a dynamic web project which references another 'utility' project. The utility project contains services, daos, etc. Compile time is fine. But when I start the web project in tomcat, I get a bunch of org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException. I know this ClassNotFound problem is not related to a single bean or it not being spelled right, because I tried commenting out the original non-critical bean that was not being found and got the same ClassNotFound errors with a bunch of other beans in the utility project.

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.

The utility project has the Java and Utility Module facets. The web project has the facets Dynamic Web Module and Java. The utility project is on the build path of the web project. I've also tried having the utility project checked in the 'Project References' property of the web project, but I don't know what the difference is between 'Project References' and having a project on the build path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open  the web project's Deployment Assembly Property Page (Project->Properties) and indicate the utility project needs to be deployed.  And unless you have something requiring you to stay on Helios, update to Indigo.  Helios is nearly two years old.